# How to get the textbox value in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, dom-events

On my page
I have one textbox and one button.
-- on the button `click` event.
 -- one function will be called. 
Now,
How to get that value of textbox and store in PHP variable? This should be done in that function which we will call on button click.

Comment: What does your code look like so far?

Comment: Theres no direct passing from javascript to PHP - as PHP is serverside and runs before the javascript (of which is clientside)

You'll probably want to POST the information to the page itself using a form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to know that Javascript and PHP run on two different servers. So they can not communicate directly.

You'll basicly have two options:

**POST the value**

Make a form with a post action, submit the form, and you can access the value in PHP with the `$_POST` array

Disadvantage is that the browser leaves the page to submit the form, but it doesn't require javascript.

**Use AJAX**

Get the value in Javascript, make an [XMLHTTPRequest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest) to the server, and you can access the variable too via `$_GET` or `$_POST`, depending on how you sent the value.

Answer (score 0):

When your page is displayed, your PHP code has already been executed.

What you want to do is to learn [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29), i.e. JS functions that call external PHP scripts.

Comment: The advice given by Glycerine is a good one too: instead of going through the perils of ajax, you may use POST. This will be much uglier, however.